# LiveCD no Unity in VirtualBox

Tags: unity, 11.04, virtualbox

I have started the Natty beta 1 ISO as a "Try Ubuntu" in a VirtualBox VM.

When it starts up there appears to be only the desktop and an "Examples" folder available - no Unity or anything.

Is this supposed to happen? Or is this a bug to report? I wanted to have a look at Natty as-is, while my "stable" Linux is using Maverick.

Comment: And after I install it I see a gnome-like UI with no unity to be seen...

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need 3D capabilities to run Unity. If youre running it in VB, you could try the Unity 2D ISO. That *might* give you the Unity design to try out.

Comment: XServer 1.10 is not yet supported in Virtual Box 4.04.

Comment: There is no Unity 2d ISO

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/14326/edit) testing Unity in Virtual Box >= 4.0 needs [Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtual-box/22745#22745) installed. This can not be done for a live CD environment as kernel modules need to be loaded.

Mind, that both Unity in 11.04, and support for 11.04 in Virtual Box are still beta and therefore likely to have issues.

Comment: This makes testing the beta very difficult - as a VM is a great place to test with.

Comment: In the meantime you can test it on USB.

Comment: Nah I have a macbook so can't boot from USB

Comment: @Russell: You could also try with an unstable [SVN version of Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) that may eventually support 11.04. I haven't tested this.